# Not able to find drop down selected value on c# after set selected value in Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I set the drop down selected value using jquery, but when trying to access this value on c# it getting null.
Jquery to set selected value:
`$([id*=ddl]).val(1);`

Comment: You need to pass the selector in quotes `$('[id*=ddl]').val(1)`, assuming it typo when posting question, However `val(1)` should work

Comment: Is the drop down value visually changing on the page when that JS is executed?

Comment: I am using $('[id*=ddl]').val(1)

Comment: No Def, it id not changing

Comment: @Naqi if the ddl is not changing it means your selector isn't getting the drop down list or there is no option with value 1. Make sure after calling `$([id*=ddl]')` that your select is in the array. Also, in the C# it is the SelectedValue property you want.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a dropdown(select), you need to find the option with the value of 1 and select i using the `selected` property

```
$('[id*=ddl]').find('option[value="1"]').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: I have tried this but still not working."ddl.SelectedItem" on c# showing null.